# Processing Excel Forms

Tags: excel

I've recently been tasked to process a great many excel forms (around 400). My job is now merely to scrape the information and place the info in four different documents. I believe a short script would serve my needs perfectly, but I want to stay the hell away from VBA if I can. Any suggestions about how to go about this and what language to choose (I don't mind learning something new)?

Comment: What languages do you know? 
.NET is quite handy for modifications of MS Office applications.

Comment: I'm not limiting myself to languages I currently know, since I'm also interested in picking up new stuff. Since this is the first time I've had to work with Windows, I think .NET will work just fine. Its just the framework, though, right? I still have to pick a language?

Comment: The following link has basic samples for office automation from C# using both early and late binding (if you only want to run this on one machine I'd go with early binding, if you'd distribute the app I'd suggest late binding): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Python as the language the fits your problem because it's [easy to learn](http://www.diveintopython.net/), scriptable, and has the right language features (in this case objects and GUI libraries) to turn your work into an application for others to use if it turns into something more than just an occasion task for you.

As for the actual Excel processing, there's a set of [Python libraries](http://www.python-excel.org/). The link also includes a 50+ PDF documentation manual with usage examples for reading, writing and manipulating workbooks.

Comment: As an aside, further research shows this library doesn't handle .xlsx. There is a project openpyxl for this, but gives the impression it's still under development: http://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#MODIFYING_AND_REWRITING_EXCEL_FILES)?

Comment: No, but the link you provided sure does make it look easy. I think I'll look into this further.